# How to add supported locales option in the localization of keycloak

Tags: java, keycloak

I am using Keycloak 20.0.1.

I want to add an option that does not exist (such as persian) to `Supported locales` combobox of localization-tab in Realm-setting menu.

How do I add this option to the combobox?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Keycloak-20 and I solved the problem by doing the following steps:

1- In the its themes directory, I created a folder that its name should be your theme name such as mytheme.

2- One of three that is used by you or all of them; it depends on you, (account, login, email) folder is created, for example I created login folder.

So till now the directory path that is created by me is :  `/mythem/login` under the `themes` directory

4- In the login directory, I created `theme.properties` that contains:

```
parent=keycloak
import=common/keycloak
locales=en,fa
```

So the message bundle of **fa** that should be in messages directory like this:

I created the messages directory into login directory; the path is: `/mytheme/login/messages` and is created **messages_fa.properties**.

5- So you can navigate to Localization tab of Keycloak setting menu and select your supported-local.

Comment: Great solution! But if I want to give the language a name, how do I do it?